# Append\Union many tables into one in R

Tags: r

I have many tables (several thousands) in a LIST (let's call it for list1). I like to append all the tables in the list1 and make a data.frame of them.
I have used the following code but it is not working.

```
library(dplyr)
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
new_df <- bind_rows(list1[i])
}
```

I have also used the following function but it is not working either.

```
stackDataInList2 <- function(x) setNames(cbind.data.frame(stack(mapply(`[`, x, 1))[[1]],
                                                          stack(mapply(`[`, x, 2))[[1]]), 
                                         names(x[[1]]))
 stackDataInList2(list1[c(1, 2, 3)])
```

Do you know other options?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example and expected outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need `for` try:

```
new_df <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(list1)) {
  new_df <- rbind(new_df, list1[[i]])
}
```

however `data.table::rbindlist(list1)` is simpler, quicker and return `data.table` (which is very convenient)

Comment: Dear friends, the only thing that works is this:            
  do.call(rbind, list(list1[[1]], list1[[2]], list1[[3]], list1[[4]])). But how can I 10000 list1? I mean something like this:              do.call(rbind, list(list1[[1]], list1[[2]], list1[[3]], list1[[4]], ... list1[[10000]])) !? Using "for i=1;10000" somehow? I don't know.

Comment: use this: `do.call(rbind, list1[1:10000])`

Comment: ok ok ok ! Thank you! It seems it is working!! However, I can't get it in Console. It looks strange in Console. Console shows only a shortcut of my table!!

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframes in your list all have the same number of columns, you can do

```
list1 <- list(iris[1:3,], iris[4:6,], iris[7:9,])
do.call(rbind, list1)
```

You can also do as follows but then you'll get a `data.table`:

```
data.table::rbindlist(list1)
```

Comment: Dear friends, the only thing that works is this: do.call(rbind, list(list1[[1]], list1[[2]], list1[[3]], list1[[4]])). But how can I 10000 list1? I mean something like this: do.call(rbind, list(list1[[1]], list1[[2]], list1[[3]], list1[[4]], ... list1[[10000]])) !? Using "for i=1;10000" somehow? I don't know.